# SwiftUI – Alert is only showing once

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a strange problem with the SwiftUI Alert view. In an ObservableObject, I do some network requests and in case of a error I will show a alert. This is my simplified model:

```swift
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    @Published var isError: Bool = false

    public func network() {
        Service.call() {
            self.isError = true

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Service.call` is a dummy for my network request. My view looks like:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel

    var body: some View {
        …
        .alert(isPresented: self.$model.isError) {
            print("Error Alert")
            return Alert(title: Text("Alert"))
        }
    }
}
```

On the first call, everything works and the alert is shown. For all further calls,`print("Error Alert")` will be executed and *Error Alert* appears in the console, but the alert is not shown.

Does anyone have any idea why Alert is only shown once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use instead (there is already default publisher for `@Published` properties)

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isError: Bool = false

    public func network() {
        Service.call() {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.isError = true // << !!! important place to call
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it doesn't work. I get this message from Xcode:

`[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`

Comment: Pay attention, in the snapshot code above there is only one change and it is on main queue. `self.isError = true` intentionally moved into main queue.

Comment: Your solution works. I have even more @Published vars and only if all (not only isError) are set in the main thread, it works. Thanks! But do you have any idea why it doesn't work with my custom ObservableObjectPublisher?

Comment: My problem is that I use a lot of computed values and this can't be @Published. So it works fine with manuelly `self.objectWillChange.send()` and it's difficult to implement it with default published.

Comment: You don't need custom `objectWillChange`, because `ObservableObject` has default one, so just call where needed `self.objectWillChange.send()` (but only on main thread - because it activates SwiftUI update)

Comment: You're right. I thought that must declared by myself.